# How can I display image or video android programming like instagram or facebook scroll auto play

Tags: android, android-layout, adapter, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

> Here is my adapter class I cannot get it to display in array if its image or video, if its video i also like it to play automatically when scroll to video. like facebook or instagram image or video.
>
> i'm able to pass it as an array but when i bind it i'm only able to bind video or image and if its video it does no automatically play it does not even display

```
   public class Adapter extends 
   RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private Context context;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        List<Datainfo> data_info = Collections.emptyList();
        public Datainfo info;
        int currentPos = 0;
        private Uri uri;
    
        // create constructor to initilize context and data sent from 
    MainActivity
        public Adapter(Context context, List<Datainfo> data_info){
            this.context = context;
            inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.data_info = data_info;
        }
    
        // Inflate the layout when viewholder created
        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup 
    parent, int viewType) {
            View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity, parent,false);
            MyHolder holder = new MyHolder(view);
            return holder;
        }
    
        // Bind data
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int 
    position) {
    
            // Get current position of item in recyclerview to bind data 
    and assign values from list
            MyHolder myHolder = (MyHolder) holder;
    
            Datainfo info = data_info.get(position);
    
            if(null != info.image) {
                myHolder.image.setImageBitmap(current.image);
                myHolder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    
            }else{
    
                myHolder.vid.setOnCompletionListener(new 
    MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        String uriPath = "https://....."; // your URL here
                        uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);
                        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                        
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                        try {
                            
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(String.valueOf(uri));
                            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); // might take 
    long! (for buffering, etc)
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
    
    
                    }
                });
    
            }
    
    
        }
    
    
        // return total item from List
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return data_info.size();
        }
    
    
        class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    
    
            private ImageView image;
            private VideoView vid;
    
            // create constructor to get widget reference
            public MyHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
               
                image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
                vid = (VideoView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.vid);
            }
    
        }
    }
```

> here is my activity layout

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fff"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:visibility="gone">
       </ImageView>

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/vid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can autoplay videos in a recyclerview using the following library:

https://github.com/Krupen/AutoplayVideos

The README.md of the libray gives a detailed description of how to use it.

Maybe it will help your issue.